# i want to show data on form fields using id with ajax

Tags: yii

how i use ajax in yii to show result against id??

```
public function actionView(){
    $model= new ViewForm();
    $model->unsetAttributes();
    if (isset($_GET['ViewJob'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_GET['ViewJob'];
    }
    $this->render('viewjob',array(
            'model'=>$model
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify you question.. If you are looking for how to use ajax in Yii then this might help u.

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/394/javascript-and-ajax-with-yii/

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/49/update-content-in-ajax-with-renderpartial/

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/388/ajax-form-submiting-in-yii/